# Should the second part of a semicolon-separated sentence be capitalised?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons

In another question this example of semicolon usage is given:

> When dinosaurs agree on something, they often high-five one another; dinosaurs are all about high-fives.

However, I have also seen the following style before, where the second part acts like a regular sentence with the first word capitalised:

> When dinosaurs agree on something, they often high-five one another; Dinosaurs are all about high-fives.

I can see the reasoning: the semicolon is bridging two sentences. Which one, if any, is correct? Is it simply a style issue?

Comment: May I see an example real-world usage of the second case? I don't remember running across it in the wild before.

Comment: @mmyers: I've seen semicolon plus capital letter bazillions of times.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you say yourself, the semicolon is *bridging* the gap between two sentences; they become one.

Wikipedia is [exceptionally succinct on this:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon#English_usage)

> **English usage**
>
> Semicolons are followed by a lower case letter, unless that letter is the first letter of a proper noun.

Comment: I don't understand: Does this answer the question? Are you saying both the sentences in the OP are acceptable? How?

Comment: @HeWhoMustBeNamed The answer is saying that since the two sentences are joined into one, get rid of the second capital letter *unless* it just so happens to belong to a proper noun.  In OP's example, 'dinosaurs' is a common noun, so according to this answer (and the cited Wikipedia page), only the lowercase version is correct.

Answer (score 8):

The Chicago Manual of Style (6.57 - 6.62) uses a small letter after the semicolon, e.g.

> Mildred intends to go to Europe; her plans, however, are still quite vague.